# После проверки записать имя пользователя

Tags: ооп, ajax, php, yii

Здравствуйте. Помогите, пожалуйста. Есть контролер, который Ajax-сом принимает значения.
Задача: после того как в проверку записать имя пользователя?

```
if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest){
    Yii::app()->user->name = 'reg';
}
```

Вот этот код не дает результата:

```
class ChekSingupController extends Controller
{        
    public function actionIndex()
    {         
       // если запрос асинхронный, то нам нужно отдать только данные
        if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest){
            if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest){
                   Yii::app()->user->name = 'reg';
            }            
            // Завершаем приложение
            Yii::app()->end();              
          }         
    }
```

Comment: @Максим147, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> после того как в проверку записать имя пользователя?

???

> Yii::app()->user->name = 'reg';

По-хорошему это и так должно сохранить все в persistent state, но можете попробовать использовать setState:

```
Yii::app()->user->setState('name', 'reg');
```

> Yii::app()->end();

Вызывать это необязательно (и не стоит).

Comment: Спасибо. Работает